# The quadratic sequence version of geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know that in quadratic sequence the second common difference is constant, so I want to apply this idea to geometric sequences, like the second ratio is constant, example :

$$ 1, 2, 8 , 64 , 1024 ... $$

so it's :
$$ ×2, ×4, ×8, ×16... $$

which is :
$$  ×2, ×2, ×2,... $$

So how do we find the $nth$ term here?

**Bonus :**

How do we find the $nth$ term in this type of sequence :

$$ 1,2,6,24,120,...$$

so it's :

$$ ×2,×3,×4,...$$

which is :

$$+1,+1,+1,+1,...$$

Comment: The $n^{th}$ term for the whole sequence?

Comment: Maybe $a_k=k\cdot a_{k-1}$, with $a_1=1$. Can you deduce $a_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence 1,2,8,64,1024 has a closed form in terms of $n$. We first write each term as a power of $2$ to search for some pattern, $u_0 = 2^0, u_1=2^1, u_2=2^3, u_3=2^6, u_4 = 2^{10}$. We can then simply conclude that at $n$, the sequence can be written as $u_n = 2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$.This is of course by pattern.

Another way to look at it, is at each stage $k$, we are multiplying $u_{k-1}$ by $2^k$, so $\frac{u_n}{u_{n-1}} = 2^n$.
Now we will consider the following product:
$$
\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{u_k}{u_{k - 1}} = \frac{u_{n}}{u_{n -1}}\times...\times\frac{u_{2}}{u_1}\times\frac{u_{1}}{u_0} = \frac{u_n}{u_0} = \prod_{k=1}^n 2^k = 2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\Rightarrow
$$
$$
\boxed{u_n = 2^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}}
$$

## Second sequence

Like what @ethan-bolker said, it's just the sequence $u_n = n!$.

Comment: Thanks, but what about a general form for the first type sequence, like for any ratio?

Comment: @ElieMakdissi yeah, just replace the $u_0$ term with $a$ (that's your starting point) and replace 2 by $r$ for instance, so you would multiply by $r,r^2,r^3,...$, the sequence $u_n = a\times r^{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}$

Comment: thanks a lot mate

Comment: aliberro - sorry for asking, but do you know any general form for the second sequence also? (like × x, ×y, ×z,... such that the difference between x and y, y and z are constant)

Comment: or like +x, +y, +z.. such that y/x, z/y.. are constant

Comment: @ElieMakdissi ask a new question please

Comment: I will, hope you'll answer there

Comment: @ElieMakdissi No worries dude

Answer (score 2):

The first sequence is $2^N$ where the exponent $N$ is the sum of the geometric series $1+2 + \cdots + k$. That sum   is well known. You can finish the details.

The second sequence is just the sequence of factorials $n!$.

Comment: is there a general form for the first sequence like for any ratio? (the second ratio is constant)

Comment: Yes, The first ratio is the base. The second ratio leads to the sum of a geometric series for the exponent.

Comment: thanks a lot mate

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you see a product of terms, it’s worth asking about what happens if you take the logarithm of the product. The product rule of logarithms allows you to turn a log of a product into a sum of logarithms, which might make a pattern easier to spot.

In your case, since you keep multiplying by 2, let’s try taking the base-2 logarithm of each term in the sequence. That gives back the sequence

$$0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, \dots$$

Do you recognize this sequence? If so, you can get a nice formula for it, then undo the logarithm by raising 2 to that power to get the solution.

Comment: Wow that's a really nice way!!+1