# General form of nth term of this type of this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

How do we find the general form of $nth$ term of a sequence like this type of sequence :

$$ 1,2,6,24,120,...$$

so it's :

$$ ×2,×3,×4,...$$

which is :

$$+1,+1,+1,+1,...$$

I mean :

Do someone know any general form for a sequence like
$$ × x, ×y, ×z,... $$
such that the difference between $x ; y$, $y; z$ are constant ;

or like $$+x, +y, +z..$$ such that $y/x$, $z/y..$ are constant?

Comment: $1 = 1!$, $2 = 1 \cdot 2 = 2!$, $6 = 2! \cdot 3 = 3!$, $\cdots$

Comment: thanks; what about the second part of question related to the general form?

Comment: The first term is $1!$. The second term is $2!$. The third term is $3!$. Do you see a pattern?

Comment: The second part of your question is about arithmetic and geometric sequences. See https://bit.ly/3F2k2ls and  https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/sequences-sums-geometric.html .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## First Part

Was answered here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4304279/772616

## Second part

If $y-x=z-y=c$ where $c$ is some constant, then the best thing we could do is:

Suppose we have the sequence $u_n$, and $\frac{u_1}{u_0} = x$, $\frac{u_2}{u_1} = y = x + c$, $\frac{u_3}{u_2} = z = x + 2c$,... Then

$$
\prod_{k=1}^n \frac{u_k}{u_{k-1}} = x(x+d)(x+2d)...(x+(n-1)c)\therefore u_n=u_0\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(x-ck)
$$

## Third Part

If $\frac{y}{x} = \frac{z}{y} = c$, then do the same thing as above.

Comment: Aha thanks a lot! I really appreciated that you answered both questions here and before :)

Comment: Are you working on something that involves these sequences?

Comment: No I was just curious about these types and some of them appeared in my homework, so..

Comment: Ahh alright, good luck ♥

Comment: thanks God bless you ❤️

Comment: bro are you from Lebanon?  I've just noticed it

Comment: @ElieMakdissi yesh, I am

Comment: kifak ya zalame?  ya alla l dene chou zghire

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131397/discussion-between-aliberro-and-elie-makdissi).